# remove duplicates from list product of tab delimited file and further classification

Tags: python, duplicates, classification, csv

I have a tab delimited file that I need to extract all of of the column 12 content from (which documents categories). However the column 12 content is highly repetitive so firstly I need to get a list that just returns the number of categories (by removing repeats). And then I need to find a way to get the number of lines per category. My attempt is as follows:

```
def remove_duplicates(l): # define function to remove duplicates
    return list(set(l))

input = sys.argv[1] # command line arguments to open tab file
infile = open(input)
for lines in infile: # split content into lines
    words = lines.split("\t") # split lines into words i.e. columns
    dataB2.append(words[11]) # column 12 contains the desired repetitive categories
    dataB2 = dataA.sort() # sort the categories
    dataB2 = remove_duplicates(dataA) # attempting to remove duplicates but this just returns an infinite list of 0's in the print command
    print(len(dataB2))
infile.close()
```

I have no idea how I would get the number of lines for each category though?
So my questions are: how do eliminate the repeats effectively? and how do I get the number of lines for each category?

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using a python [Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html) to implement this. A counter does almost exactly what you are asking for and so your code would look like follows:

```
from collections import Counter
import sys

count = Counter()

# Note that the with open()... syntax is generally preferred.
with open(sys.argv[1]) as infile:
  for lines in infile: # split content into lines
      words = lines.split("\t") # split lines into words i.e. columns
      count.update([words[11]])

print count
```

Comment: It's a nit, but I'd move both the initialization and printing of the counter outside of the `with` block, since they don't need to be in there.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is read each line from a file, split it by tabs, grab column 12 for each line and put it in a list. (if you don't care about repeating lines just make `column_12 = set()` and use `add(item)` instead of `append(item)`). Then you simply use len() to get the length of the collection. Or if you want both you can use a list and change it to a set later.

EDIT: To count each catagory (Thank you Tom Morris for alerting me to the fact I didn't actually answer the question). You iterate over the set of column_12 so as to not count anything more than once and use lists built in `count()` method.

```
with open(infile, 'r') as fob:
    column_12 = []
    for line in fob:
        column_12.append(line.split('\t')[11])

print 'Unique lines in column 12 %d' % len(set(column_12))
print 'All lines in column 12 %d' % len(column_12)
print 'Count per catagory:'
for cat in set(column_12):
    print '%s - %d' % (cat, column_12.count(cat))
```

Comment: That doesn't provide the count per category, which the question asks for.

Comment: Ahh yes, right you are, I miss-read the question. Let me fix this.